# Echo Returns "n"

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm using a Controller in AngularJS which calls http.post twice. The first one is just to get values from MySQL row , while the other is just for Updating the MySQL row. The problem is, in the 2nd http.post, the echo adds `n` before the variable that is supposed to be returned.

Call of 1st PHP file

```
$http.post("endpoints/EditProfilePage.php", data).success(function(response)
echo:
$userInfo = $userInfo->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($userInfo);
```

This 1st echo gathers columns from a database.

Call of 2nd PHP file:

```
$http.post("endpoints/EditProfilePage2.php", data).success(function(response)
echo:
echo json_encode($username);
```

This 2nd echo should only return a single column/variable.

I think it's not a problem with the `json_encode` as I've already tried echoing a simple text.

The output is `n"7@7"` when I use `echo json_encode($username);`

while it's `ntext` when I use `echo "text";`

Comment: put exit after echoing something

Comment: Can you check if you have an `n` somewhere before an opening PHP tag? I used to have a similar issue, because I was using a shortcut to reformat my code before saving, but missed the `cmd` key - causing a character to be inserted before the open tag.

Comment: Wow thank you @PhilippFlenker :)) I didn't know that could happen. I was staring in the middle of the code the whole time.

Comment: Glad I could help!